# How to grab a value after a specific text?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to grab the value after the string 'Estrato:' and 'Piso No:'

```
<ul class="boxcube">
<!--area-->
<li><b>Área Const.:</b><br/>
                        90,00 m²</li>
<!--Estrato si aplica-->
</li><li><b>Estrato:</b><br/>
                    5         
                </li>
<!--edad si aplica-->
<li><b>Antigüedad:</b><br/>
                        1 a 8 años</li>
<!--piso #-->
<li><b>Piso No:</b><br/>
                        6º</li>
</ul>
```

here is my code

```
      try:
        estrato=soup.find('ul',class_='boxcube').find(string=re.compile("Estrato:")).next_sibling
      except:
        estrato='NA'
      try:
        piso=soup.find('ul',class_='boxcube').find(string=re.compile("Piso No:")).next_sibling
      except:
        piso='NA'
```

which returns me None in both cases.

The result i want is

```
Piso: 6
Estrato: 5
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code how to find text next to desired elements:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<ul class="boxcube">
<!--area-->
<li><b>Área Const.:</b><br/>
                        90,00 m²</li>
<!--Estrato si aplica-->
</li><li><b>Estrato:</b><br/>
                    5         
                </li>
<!--edad si aplica-->
<li><b>Antigüedad:</b><br/>
                        1 a 8 años</li>
<!--piso #-->
<li><b>Piso No:</b><br/>
                        6º</li>
</ul>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

e = soup.select_one('b:-soup-contains("Estrato:")').find_next_sibling(text=True)
p = soup.select_one('b:-soup-contains("Piso No:")').find_next_sibling(text=True)

print("Piso:", p.strip())
print("Estrato:", e.strip())
```

Prints:

```
Piso: 6º
Estrato: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get(yoururl)
soup = r.text #or r.content

for x in soup.find_all("li"):
    if 'Estrato' in x.text:
         print((x.text).replace("\n", ""))

    if 'Piso' in x.text:
         print((x.text).replace("\n", ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
html_doc = """
<ul class="boxcube">
    <!--area-->
    <li><b>Área Const.:</b><br/>
                        90,00 m²</li>
    <!--Estrato si aplica-->
    </li>
    <li><b>Estrato:</b><br/>
                    5         
                </li>
    <!--edad si aplica-->
    <li><b>Antigüedad:</b><br/>
                        1 a 8 años</li>
    <!--piso #-->
    <li><b>Piso No:</b><br/>
                        6º</li>
</ul>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getSpecificValue(doc):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)
    specificField = ['Estrato', 'Piso']
    values = {}
    for li in soup.findAll('li'):
        b_field = li.b.get_text()
        for field in specificField:
            if b_field.find(field) != -1:
                values[field] = list(li.children)[-1].strip()
    return values
```